# adjust ruby view code logic front ui item not displaying correctly

Tags: ruby, frontend, blacklight

Hi I am new to ruby and I have a front ui that I am working on which have an issue displaying certain types of items I am specifying from solr index to display in an mvc ruby blacklight ui, see the snippet below:

```html
      <!-- ORAL HISTORY  -->
      <% elsif document.id =~/oh/ %>

       <iframe src="/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=%2Fdocpdfview%2F<%=@document.id%>" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen style="width: 100%; height: 640px"></iframe>
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Download</button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item" target="_blank" href="/pdfdownload/<%=@document.id%>">PDF</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" target="_blank" href="/txt/<%=@document.id%>">Plain Text</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" target="_blank" href="/dc/<%=@document.id%>">Metadata (Dublin Core)</a>
        </div>

        <video id="videoarea" controls="controls" poster="" src=""></video>
        <% @document["rdf.fedora.hasPart"].each do |item| %>
          <ul id="playlist">
            <li movieurl="/mp3/<%=item%>"><%=item%></li>
          </ul>
        <% end %>
                <br><br>

        <% @document["rdf.fedora.hasPart"].each do |item| %>
                  <%=item%>
          <div class="preview_image" align="left">
            <video class="video-js vjs-fluid vjs-default-skin"
              controls=""
              data-setup='{ "aspectRatio":"640:120"}'
              playsinline=""
              poster="/pageturnerserver/ajaxp?theurl=http://localhost:8080/fedora/get/<%=@document.id%>/Preview"
              preload="none">
              <source
                src="/mp3/<%=item%>"
                type="video/mp4">
            </video>
          </div>
        <% end %>

      <!-- AUDIO  -->
      <% elsif document.id =~/aud/ %>
            <div class="preview_image" align="left">
                  <video class="video-js vjs-fluid vjs-default-skin"
                    controls=""
                    data-setup='{ "aspectRatio":"640:120"}'
                    playsinline=""
                    poster="/pageturnerserver/ajaxp?theurl=http://localhost:8080/fedora/get/<%=@document.id%>/Preview"
                    preload="none">
                    <source src="/mp3/<%=@document.id%>" type="video/mp4">
                  </video>
                </div>
```

this is not displaying correctly in my ui in case where the " @document["rdf.fedora.hasPart"].each do |item|"  item does not have "rdf.fedora.hasPart", is there a way I can build in the ruby code view logic for if rdf.fedora.haspart to handle when ["rdf.fedora.hasPart"] is none and | item| is none?

thanks in advance, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can run any ruby code inside a view in rails. For your problem you can solve like this:

```
  <% if @document["rdf.fedora.hasPart"].present? %>
     # Do something if @document["rdf.fedora.hasPart"] has element inside
  <% else %>
     # Do something if @document["rdf.fedora.hasPart"] has no element inside
  <% end %>
```